# Should I use em dash, comma, or a semicolon in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons, em-dashes

"It was established the day my best friend introduced us to each other, much to my delight, and his chagrin." 
or 
"... each other—much to my delight, and his chagrin." 
or 
"... each other; much to my delight, and his chagrin."

Thank you!

Comment: The semicolon can't really be justified, but the other two work, especially (for the comma choice) if you drop the comma after _delight_. Use the dash if you want a more dramatic pause.

Answer (score 0):

Since "It was established the day my best friend introduced us to each other" is a legal complete sentence, a comma is a poor choice, making the complete sentence a run-on.
Using a semicolon indicates that the sentence can end where it is, and that you are adding another adjoining thought to round it out.
The dash is better, though, showing a break in thought and thereby adding emphasis to the delight/chagrin aspect, which appears to be the thing you are actually trying to emphasize here.

Answer (score 0):

RULE #1 FOR THE EM DASH: Use an em dash (--)to indicate an interruption or an abrupt change in thought or to insert supplemental information. If the insertion comes in the middle of a sentence, add a closing dash to signal the end of the interruption.

Example:

```
 Faith, hope, and love--these virtues are very important to me.

 Last week--I think it was Wednesday--the manual was published and distributed.
```

RULE #2 FOR EM DASH: Use an em dash (--) for emphasis in statements or examples.

Example:

```
 The only exception--and it is rare--is when an extreme emergency arises.
```

RULE #3 FOR THE EM DASH: Use an em dash (--) to set off an entire phrase that has commas within it.

Example:

```
 A solid-colored top--such as the black sweater, the brown vest, or the red shirt--would look best.
```

RULE #4 FOR THE EM DASH: Use an em dash (--) before the source of a quotation when the source is listed after the quotation.

Example:

```
 "Proper words in proper places makes the true definition of a style."--Jonathan Swift
```

Comment: Please add sources to support your answer.